# How to get CookieName used in CookieRequestCultureProvider?

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-core

During Startup of ASP.NET Core application we can enable request based localization with `UseRequestLocalization` method. This method accepts options where I can specify corresponding providers. One of them is `CookieRequestCultureProvider` which have CookieName property.
Our app changes this name during startup. And if I understand all correctly we should set culture cookie manually when we want to involve this culture request provider in work.

We can assume that cookie will be set somewhere in some controller. Let's say it is default action of home controller or login action of membership controller as most obvious scenarios when we need to make it persistent on client side.

So my question is exactly about this CookieName.
How to get this string value in the place when cookie should be created and set?

You can suggest me to save cookie name in some place during startup.
But it is not desired behavior... I want to make app more robust: considering current configuration only.. and not the original process of configuration.

I tried to check features for that purpose:
`this.HttpContext.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>().Provider`

But this feature contains only specific provider (source of culture) or null if culture is set in some different way.

So does asp.net core team provide the solution to get cookie name inside controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, if you are using the default cookie name, its easy:

```
CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName
```

If not, you will need get the instance of "RequestLocalizationOptions"

```
var locOptions = (IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>) HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>));
```

This instance will give you access to all providers. But you need only the Cookie provider, so...

```
var provider = locOptions.Value.RequestCultureProviders.SingleOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == typeof(CookieRequestCultureProvider));
```

Finally, with the correct provider, you can get the cookie name:

```
var cookieName = ((CookieRequestCultureProvider)provider).CookieName;
```

All the best!

** **EDIT** **
The code to change the cookie name:

```
var options = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();

// Find the cookie provider with LINQ
var cookieProvider = options.Value.RequestCultureProviders
    .OfType<CookieRequestCultureProvider>()
        .First();
// Set the new cookie name
cookieProvider.CookieName = "NEW-NAME";

app.UseRequestLocalization(options.Value);
```

Comment: I think many things changed since that moment and on that moment I solved the issue in different way. But this answer looks promising only in theory. I can guess in your code you get fresh copy of options with default collection of RequestCultureProviders. It is not the same object of options used at Startup. So I cannot see in that default collection the instance of my own CookieCultureProvider (declared as "public class CookieCultureProvider : RequestCultureProvider"). Therefore I cannot extract any its property including CookieName.

Comment: Hi, @Maxim. The code works perfectly for me. Please check if you are changing the cookie name like I explain on Configure method of Statup

Comment: Now it is pretty clear what you are talking about. And in my case I just need fill that instance by own providers and it will work. In other words we need to hold this object by some 3rd-party. And it is exactly what I am doing for my custom config object (containing cookie name). Considering original question it can be accepted as answer... I think most important information is that we need to use IOptions<T> service to create and fetch any options at any place.